Kde 6 & Konsole shortcuts Alt+D
In a recent update of Konsole (I assume from the upgrade to kde6 but I'm not sure) i can’t use the shortcut alt+D to delete the current word in the terminal because it split horizontally the screen.
I have looked up the shortcut in konsole settings file es .config/kglobalshortcutsrc and .config/khotkeysrc but there is not a defined shortcut with alt+D so I don’t know if it is embedded or what.
Is there any way to change it or disable it?
